# MongoDB Update a document and add new property

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using the C# 3.2 driver and trying to insert or update a document, and also (potentially) add some new fields. My code looks like this:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("User");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("UserID", "mkemp");

var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
        .Set("FirstName", "Mike")
        .Set("LastName", "Kemp");


update.AddToSet("Age", "57");

var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update , new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = true });
```

The FirstName and LastName get created, but the Age field doesn't get created or updated. I am saving the data based on a form post, so I don't know in advance what fields are going to be posted. Is there any way to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 3):

It's easier than you think: in Mongo, if a property doesn't exist is created instead.

`AddToSet` isn't to set simple values, but it's to add items to an array stored in a given property name and it implements *set* semantics. That is, if you use `AddToSet` to add items, you'll create an array of unique items ([taken from Mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)):

> The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is
>   already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array.

See the following [docs for `$set`:](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

> If the field does not exist, $set will add a new field with the
>   specified value, provided that the new field does not violate a type
>   constraint. If you specify a dotted path for a non-existent field,
>   $set will create the embedded documents as needed to fulfill the
>   dotted path to the field.

Comment: So what method am I looking for to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @MillinMo Double check my answer: you need to use `Set` too :D

Comment: I changed the code to

var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
            .Set("FirstName", "Mike")
            .Set("LastName", "Kemp12121212");

        update.Set("Age", "27");

but it still doesn't add the field to the document

Comment: @MillinMo I'll try it tomorrow, but I believe you should be doing something wrong

Comment: I would very appreciative. I am banging my head against the wall with this.

Comment: I guess what I really need is some sample code in c# that shows me how I can do this.

Comment: @MillinMo In fact, MongoDB C# driver docs redirects you to `$set` documentation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but got it working, here is my code:

```
 var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("CollectionName");

        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("UserID", "mkemp");
        var update = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<BsonDocument>().Set("PropertyName", "PropertyValue");

        var result = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);

        log.Write($"Added {propertyName} property to {result.ModifiedCount} documents");
```

In my case I wanted to add a property to all documents if it did not exist already, so I did this:

```
 private async Task AddDecimalPropertyAsync(string propertyName, IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection, ILog log)
    {
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists(propertyName, false);
        var update = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<BsonDocument>().Set(propertyName, 0m);

        var result = await collection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update);

        log.Write($"Added {propertyName} decimal property to {result.ModifiedCount} documents");
    }
```